# How to avoid connection timeout when server sends response late?

Tags: java, sockets, http, curl, router

I have built a server which does some action(run some scripts) which takes around 10 seconds and then sends response to client.

When I make curl call from the same server using

```
curl http://localhost/get-me-status
```

I have it working properly but when I make

```
$ curl http://server/get-me-status
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Currently my server doesn't send any response to client for around 10 seconds till the action on its side is completed. How do I keep the socket alive till the client gets response? My server is currently in Java and I use vertx on server side.

My impression is that one of the intermediatery router is killing the connection after seeing that the connection is idle for few seconds since it is working fine when client is also in the same machine. Is there any way I keep sending noob or any other messages to client to keep the connection alive?

I face this problem even when I do http request from the browser.

Comment: curl has a timeout option: you can use -m <seconds> , read [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout/94612)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using Tomcat to handle this for you.

Comment: I have never used tomcat. Does using tomcat solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the **client connection timeout**. In `curl`, set the options [`--connect-timeout`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--connect-timeout) and [`--max-time`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-m).